# iphone push notification badge number increment

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How to increment the badge number and how to know whether the user opens the notifications.so v could know whether to increment the badge no or to start from the beginning(as 1).

here

```
alertNotification.Payload.Badge = 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot increment or decrement badge number using push-notifications. You can only set **NEW** `value`!

You can know current badge value only if your application is now running.

If you extremely want to add such feature you should store current user's badge value at your server and send appropriate value with your push-notification.

P.S. It's very strange that Apple didn't think about it when they were developing badge numbers and push-notifications. =(

Comment: so wat is the way to to do this now?

Comment: ???? What did you not understand? Just don't send badge or implement such functionality at server or always set 1 as badge value

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple deliberately doesn't support incremental updates, in order to avoid race conditions since they don't guarantee the order of delivery in case of multiple messages.